# What is correct or suggested approach to send the signal name through 'kill' command?

Tags: linux, kill, signals, options

I read many tutorials about the use of `kill` command, *mostly* 3 approaches

```
kill -15 <pid>
kill -SIGTERM <pid>
kill -TERM <pid>
```

For scripts purposes and for portability with macos too, the code numbers are not going to be used. Because `kill -l` in macos is different than Linux. So here enter in play the signal names.

**Question**

- What is the correct or suggested approach to send the **signal name** through the `kill` command?

I mean:

- **SIG***something* or *something*?

And why? These 2 approaches exists for one reason, right? is there a mandatory reason to use an approach over the other?

**Environment**

This situation is for Ubuntu Desktop/Server and Fedora Workstation/Server

Comment: And your example with SIGTERM is not good (IMHO) because in Linux you can have the same result executing `kill <PID>`

Comment: @RomeoNinov I know SIGTERM is the default signal, it was used only for demonstration purposes, it could be for either: SIGTSTP, SIGSTOP, SIGKILL, SIGCONT etc ...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The most portable variant is

```
kill -s TERM -- …
```

That’s the form specified [in POSIX with no extensions](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/kill.html): `-s` followed by the signal’s name, as defined [in `signal.h`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/signal.h.html), with no `SIG` prefix, or 0 for the “null” signal (used to check for the existence of a process with a given identifier).

`SIGTERM` is the default signal, so sending that to processes or process groups can be done using the following canonical forms:

```
kill <pid>
kill -- -<pgid>
```

On Linux in general, most implementations of `kill` (including shell builtins) accept signals as numbers or names with or without a `SIG` prefix; notable exceptions include the `kill` builtin of dash, which is the default `/bin/sh` in Debian-based distributions, and of [the Schily Bourne Shell](http://schilytools.sourceforge.net/bosh.html).

There’s no “mandatory” reason to use one form rather than another, among whatever forms are supported by the tools you use. I would personally avoid numeric forms because they can appear to be ambiguous: is `kill -9 -15` intended to send `SIGTERM` to process groups 9 and 15, or `SIGKILL` to process group 15? (It’s the latter, but some readers may wonder.) I would also omit the `SIG` prefix since that’s not recognised everywhere.

Note that POSIX does specify a few numeric signal values:

| Number | Signal |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | “Null” signal |
| 1 | `HUP` |
| 2 | `INT` |
| 3 | `QUIT` |
| 6 | `ABRT` |
| 9 | `KILL` |
| 14 | `ALRM` |
| 15 | `TERM` |

Comment: `kill -9` has been a common idiom since time immemorial. Maybe it would be better to use a different example, since most other signal numbers are not well known.